# Browser crashes at changing certain iframe src attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

I got these pages:

- http://fiddle.jshell.net/Frondor/2wdauscv/show/light/ (master)
- http://fiddle.example.com/iframe1 (iframe)
- http://fiddle.example.com/iframe2 (iframe)
- http://fiddle.example.com/iframe3 (iframe)

I want to be able to change the **iframe** showing at "**master**" with jQuery by manipulating its `src` attribute.

I've tried it here:

### http://jsfiddle.net/Frondor/86960cyw/

but everytime I try to use the form, my browser (chrome) **crashes**. Which is really weird! Becase I've tried with some other iframes and it seems to be working fine:

### http://jsfiddle.net/Frondor/2wdauscv/

I know I might be dealing with the same-origin-policy, but I'm trying to figure out a workaround for it, since I have access to the iframes source code, I can set up a header or something to allow my "master" page change the iframes with jQuery.

---

Now I'm thinking that same-origin policy has nothing to do with it, since I can really do what I want on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Frondor/2wdauscv/) example. I'm really really confused about it

Comment: Iframes can be buggy. Maybe try loading the page into a div with ajax as an alternative.

Comment: Enlighten me please :)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments. You can just use .load() to load the page into a div instead of using an iframe.

HTML

```
<form action="#">
    <select name="changeIframe" id="select">
        <option value="cafeteria">cafeteria</option>
        <option value="confiteria">confiteria</option>
        <option value="pasteleria">pasteleria</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$( "#container" ).load( "http://lordfede.byethost13.com/ferreteria.php" ); //Load the first "iframe" page
    $('#select').on("change", function (e) {
        var iframe = "http://lordfede.byethost13.com/" + $(this).val() + ".php";        
        e.preventDefault();
        $( "#container" ).load( iframe );
    });
});
```

Comment: Well... This isn't a solution for me, since its screwing the scripts at my iframe pages. .load() method is not rendering the scripts so Its useless for me. See: jsfiddle.net/Frondor/k00hcqod and by the way, I should add `<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>` in order to make your example work

Comment: Can you just put the script on the master html page? How load works is it just inserts the html from the other page into the div. So the scripts from that page can just be put with your other scripts.

Comment: Its not working, see my iframe source code: http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=r9E2ZaHS ----- 1) I'm using php for $timestamp AND 2) I shall convert that script to work with cross-domain ajax requests, because `master` is not hosted on a webserver, I can't use php on master pages, that's why I need these iframes. See http://jsfiddle.net/Frondor/k00hcqod